column_name_character_map in LoadJobConfig
I am looking to apply column_name_character_map=V2 setting using below
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    column_name_character_map='V2',
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)

But I am getting error, is it not possible to enable column_name_character_map using Python? -
Property column_name_character_map is unknown for <class 'google.cloud.bigquery.job.load.LoadJobConfig'>


Hi @MysticRose,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. Do consider upvoting and accepting if it solves your issue, otherwise let me know so that we can solve further.

According to this google cloud documentation  LoadJobConfig supports column_name_character_map.
To solve the above error,consider upgrading to the latest version.
pip install  --upgrade  google-cloud-bigquery
Before upgrading  please go through the release note and identify the changes.
